# 現在実行中のスクリプトについて、 symlink を解決したパスを取得する方法はありますか。

Tags: bash, ubuntu

今現在実行中のスクリプトは、 `$0` であったり `${BASH_SOURCE[0]}` などで取得できるのは理解しています。しかし、これらは symlink であった場合、 symlink  を含んだようなパスになっていることを先ほど確認しました。

質問:

- 現在実行しているスクリプトに対して、 symlink を解決した本体のありかを取得することはできますか？

背景:

- シェルスクリプトが利用するリソースファイルを本体の相対パスで指定したく、その際にスクリプト本体のみを symlink した場合にも正しく動作させたいから

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ファイルのパスのシンボリックリンクを解決するコマンドとして `readlink`(1) があります。これを利用しましょう。

Answer (score 2):

`realpath`はどうでしょうか。

```
~$ cat test.sh 
realpath $0
~$ ln -s test.sh lntest.sh
~$ file lntest.sh 
lntest.sh: symbolic link to test.sh
~$ ./test.sh 
/home/xxx/test.sh
~$ ./lntest.sh
/home/xxx/test.sh
```